# python cbpro api problems appending data

Tags: python

This script should be printing every order for every second for a two minute duration, but the csv file just has the the same row repeated. Sample data from the csv is below.

```
import cbpro
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
import json

public_client = cbpro.PublicClient()
res = json.dumps(public_client.get_product_ticker(product_id='BTC-USD'))
csv_file = "cbpro-test-1.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame()  
timeout = time.time() + 60*2 
while True:
    converted = json.loads(res)
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(converted), orient='columns'))
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    
df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

here is some sample output of the csv:

```
trade_id,price,size,time,bid,ask,volume
127344793,32750.24,0.00113286,2021-01-29T06:18:58.637859Z,32750.24,32755.06,41795.68551358
127344793,32750.24,0.00113286,2021-01-29T06:18:58.637859Z,32750.24,32755.06,41795.68551358
127344793,32750.24,0.00113286,2021-01-29T06:18:58.637859Z,32750.24,32755.06,41795.68551358
127344793,32750.24,0.00113286,2021-01-29T06:18:58.637859Z,32750.24,32755.06,41795.68551358
```

edit: I moved the  public client and the res variable to inside the loop and it works somewhat, it skips a second data looks like this now:

```
127347670,32620.2,0.00307689,2021-01-29T06:33:50.16111Z,32610,32620.12,41966.5764529
127347670,32620.2,0.00307689,2021-01-29T06:33:50.16111Z,32610,32620.12,41966.5764529
127347671,32614.11,0.00146359,2021-01-29T06:33:52.491186Z,32610,32610.01,41966.5764529
127347671,32614.11,0.00146359,2021-01-29T06:33:52.491186Z,32610,32610.01,41966.5764529
```

it goes from 06:33:50 to 06:33:52, the rest of the file follows the same format

tried with this while loop:

```
while True:
    public_client = cbpro.PublicClient()
    res = json.dumps(public_client.get_product_ticker(product_id='BTC-USD'))
    converted = json.loads(res)
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.json_normalize(converted), orient='columns'))
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: I thought I did, thats the whole script and the results are what I posted underneath

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values and isolate the problem to the point you don't understand.  You have imported *five* packages.  You fetch data, convert it to a data frame, normalize it, convert to CSV, ...

Answer (score 0):

You fetch only one quote, before you enter the loop.  Then you repeatedly process that same data.  You never change `res`, you simply keep appending the same values to you DF, one iteration after another.  You need to fetch repeatedly using `get_product_ticker`.

**After OP update:**
Yes, that's how to get the quotations rapidly.  You can do it better if you move that first line above the loop: you don't need to re-create the client object on every iteration.

Several lines are identical because you're fetching real-time quotations.  If nobody changes the current-best bid or ask price, then the quotation remains static.  If you want only the changes, then use the `unique` method of PANDAS to remove the duplicates.

Comment: well i did add an update mentioning that I tried it with the variable res and public_client in the loop, the results from that are the second list of data. With the code set like that it seemed to write the same row several times then skips a second and then do it it again. Ive tried it both ways and its just not getting the data correctly, Im not sure what else to try..